# Puede optimizarse aún más este método BubbleSort?

Tags: java, revisión-de-código, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy tratando de hacer un método Bubblesort que haga ordenamientos ascendentes y descendentes bajo demanda, duplicando además, durante la implementación, la menor cantidad posible de código.

Hasta ahora mi solución temporal:

```
public void burbuja(){
    String TipoOrdenamiento= "Max";
    int i,j,aux;



    for(i=1;i<A.length;i++){
        for(j=A.length-1; j>=i; j--){

            if(TipoOrdenamiento=="Min"){
                if(A[j-1] >A [j]){
                    aux= A[j-1];
                    A[j-1]= A[j];
                    A[j]= aux;
                }
            }
            if(TipoOrdenamiento=="Max"){
                if(A[j-1] <A [j]){
                    aux= A[j-1];
                    A[j-1]= A[j];
                    A[j]= aux;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Como verán la diferencia entre un ordenamiento ascendente y uno descendente es muy pequeña. Mi pregunta es si este método ya ha sido reducido hasta su mínima expresión o consideran ustedes que este código todavía tiene margen para seguir siendo compactado. De ser así ¿de qué manera podría encontrarse una mejor solución? (mejor solución en términos de mínima cantidad de código "clonado").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios puntos por mejorar (las 2 primeras ya mencionadas por @Dev. Joel):

1. Comparación de cadenas es mediante `equals`, no con `==`.
2. El arreglo a ordenar y el tipo de ordenamiento deberían ser parámetros.
3. Si no se indica un tipo de ordenamiento apropiado, no se realizará ninguna acción.
4. Deben validarse los argumentos al comienzo para evitar problemas en la ejecución del método: variables que no sean nulas, etc.
5. Los tipos de ordenamiento deberían ser evaluados por minúsculas o mayúsculas para evitar problemas como enviar "mIn", "min", "MIN", etc.
6. La estrategia de comparación puede ser evaluada una sola vez y el resto del código mantenerse igual.
7. Lo que estás implementando es la forma más ineficiente del algoritmo de burbuja. Por ejemplo, si el arreglo a ordenar ya estuviese ordenado, entonces igual realizará NxN iteraciones, donde N es la longitud del arreglo. Una implementación más apropiada revisa si durante la ejecución hubo algún cambio, de manera que debería seguir intentando ordenar el arreglo, y si no hubieron cambios entonces el arreglo ya se encuentra ordenado.

Voy a proveer una implementación basada en tu código y las mejoras sugeridas, incluyendo el beneficio de usar Java 8:

```
static final String TIPO_ORDEN_MIN = "min";

//punto 2
public void burbuja(int[] A, String tipoOrdenamiento) {
    //punto 4
    if (A == null) return; //no hacer nada porque el arreglo es nulo
    //punto 5
    tipoOrdenamiento = tipoOrdenamiento == null ? "" : tipoOrdenamiento.trim().toLowerCase(); //
    //punto 5
    //por defecto, que ordene de menor a mayor
    BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> comparadorOrden = (x, y) -> x > y;
    //puntos 1 y 3
    //extra: usualmente los valores que sabemos que no van a variar
    //deben declararse como constantes como es el caso de
    //la variable TIPO_ORDEN_MIN
    //y siempre se deben comparar las constantes contra las variables
    //no al revés
    if (TIPO_ORDEN_MIN.equals(tipoOrdenamiento)) {
        comparadorOrden = (x, y) -> x < y;
    }
    //variable para limitar la cantidad de iteraciones (punto 7)
    boolean cambio = true;
    for (i = 1; cambio && i < A.length; i++) {
        //por defecto, asumimos que no habrán cambios en esta iteración
        cambio = false;
        for (j = A.length-1; j >= i; j--) {
            if (comparadorOrden.test(A[j-1, j], A[j])) {
                int aux = A[j-1];
                A[j-1] = A[j];
                A[j] = aux;
                //si hubo un cambio, actualizar la variable
                cambio = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Algunas cuestiones para modificar en su programa

- Comparar Strings con `equals();` no con `==`

  ```
  if(TipoOrdenamiento.toLowerCase().equals("min")){...}
  if(TipoOrdenamiento.toLowerCase().equals("max")){...}
  ```
- El tipo de Ordenamiento se puede pasar por parámetro al método

  ```
  public void burbuja(String TipoOrdenamiento){...}
  ```